# keras:How to map prediction to labels?

Tags: keras, scikit-learn

I have trained a keras model. Before training, I used skelarn's LabelBinarizer to map each image's label to probability vector. There are 120 labesl in total, so each probability vector has 120 values.

So now when I use model to make predictions then I would get probability vector.

How can I map this vector to labels? I guess I need to make use of LabelBinarizer as it encapsulates the knowledge of labels. But I am not sure how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say we have 6 data points with 3 unique classes (In your case there are 120 unique classes)

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
lb = preprocessing.LabelBinarizer()
Y = ["l1", "l2", "l3", "l3", "l2", "l2", "l1"]
Y_bin = lb.fit_transform(Y) # label binarizer will convert it to a 0/1's
print(Y_bin)
```

`Y_bin` will look like this

```
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0]])
```

The `LabelBinarizer` will have the knowledge of which labels were marked l1, l2 or l3. From above we see, it marked `l1` as `[1,0,0]`, `l2` as `[0,1,0]` and `l3` as `[0,0,1]`. this will reflect in the `.classes_` attribute of `LabelBinarizer` which would be -`print(lb.classes_)`

```
array(['l1', 'l2', 'l3'], dtype='<U2')
```

So now say your output for 2 points was -

```
out = np.array([[.75, .2, .05]
              , [.3, .02, .68]])
```

For the first point, the model has selected the first label and for the second point, it selected label 3

Those labels can be selected using the below code -

```
max_idx = out.argmax(axis=1) #get the indexes for the max probabilities
out_labels = [lb.classes_[i] for i in max_idx]
print(out_labels)
```

That will give labels -

```
['l1', 'l3']
```